# Separate tabs for different phases on Area51?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase

The proposals in the commitment phase are currently at the top of the "hot" and "progress" tabs on Area51.

Would it make sense to create either a separate area or separate tabs for these different phases, so that discussion proposals can get more attention?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, I think the current system is more effective. It slows down the rate of discussion proposals, which you mentioned, but I think that this is better because it's acting as a rate-limiter. If we separated them, then there would be more commitment proposals, thus diluting everyone's attention and fewer proposals might get to beta because there would be so many of them that everyone might not pick the same 3 to commit to.

Comment: I, for one, only commit to proposals that are really relevant to me.  I've only committed to one proposal so far, because there are two or three more in discussion that are really interesting.  I expect that we could rely on other people to do the same, regardless of how many commitment proposals exist?

Comment: "It slows down the rate of discussion proposals...this is better because it's acting as a rate-limiter."  Brought to you by the Department of Redundancy Department.